# Emulator: qemu-system-i386.exe. Permission Denied

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

Working on a test app, where I have a website where you can enter in news, that will get sent into a database using php. I turn that into json with php and try to parse it into the app. When I try to run the app I get the following error:
**Emulator: qemu-system-i386.exe: Unable to open C:\Users\User\.android\avd\Nexus_5X_API_25_x86.avd\data\misc\pstore\pstore.bin: Permission denied.**

**What i've tried:** I tried going to the files location, right clicking, opening properties and unchecking "Read Only". That does not work, and after I run the emulator it sets it to Read Only mode again. I've tried unchecking Read Only while Android Studio is open and closed.
I've also added the following line to AndroidManifest.xml file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

When I run the emulator, it does not show anything, just a black screen, when I press the turn off button on the side I can see the phone and when I try to run the app from the menu it will say that the app has crashed. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Just had this problem. Deleted the project and recreated it with the same project name - issue persisted. Deleted the project again and recreated it with a different project name - now ok

Comment: Happens with whatever project name I use, Fortunately it does not seem to be the cause of the crash so the error doesn't seem to affect me.